# Expand FlatList height along with collapsible header in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-animatable

[image]

In the above image, blue boxes represents `FlatList`.

When I scroll down in the `FlatList`, I want the green and yellow view to move above the screen and I want the green part to be sticky at top of the screen while the yellow view disappears from the top of the screen.

I've been able to move yellow view above screen and make the green view sticky at top. 
But I also want the `FlatList` to move along when the green view moves above it, dynamically changing the height of `FlatList`.

Comment: take a look at these two packages...  you can use them and make some change to achieve what you want. https://github.com/kyaroru/RNParallax  https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-header-scroll-view

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a custom collapsible header in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55021560/how-to-create-a-custom-collapsible-header-in-react-native)